# Automatically set child.parent_id when parent.children<< child?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How to do that with ActiveRecord? My code:

```
p = Product.create
l = Label.create
p.labels.add << l
```

But I get `l.parent == nil`

```
  create_table "labels", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
  end
```

Comment: Could someone with mod powers please edit that to "ActiveRecord"?  I realize that this question is a lost cause in its current state, but maybe it can be salvaged a bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some code from you would be appropriate, since what you're asking should be working automatically.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

If your code doesn't resemble that, then please post a more specific question.

Edit: 
Does your `Product` model have any validations in it?  They aren't going to pass your code above, and you aren't checking the return value from `create`, so you'll never know.

Comment: See my edit above about validations.  Posting your model code would help, if that isn't it.

Comment: Not sure why. I changed something and change them back. But everything now working. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `acts_as_tree` for this: http://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree

Comment: Shouldn't that be done some lower-level? No matter it's a tree or a list, child.parent_id should be set when a parent include it?